# Aws Lambda function returns confidence 99% to anything i upload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am doing some thing wrong over here, while comparing two images in different S3 Bucket.

Even though, I am comparing images of male and female it would give 99% confidence

or am i missing something in the declaration yet

Maybe This line is causing a problem

> key_target = "targett/" + key

Or my event code is error prone this is where i have mentioned my source bucket ,even though i have mentioned it in lambda function for testing below. What else do i need to correct so that it will return the confidence within the rang specified

```
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
from decimal import Decimal
import json
import urllib

print('Loading function')

rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')
#iot = boto3.client('iot-data')


 # --------------- Helper Functions to call Rekognition APIs ------------------

def compare_faces(bucket, key, key_target, threshold=75):
response = rekognition.compare_faces(
    SourceImage={
        "S3Object": {
            "Bucket": 'dacss',
            "Name": 'obama.jpg',
        }
    },
    TargetImage={
        "S3Object": {
            "Bucket": 'targett',
            "Name": 'michelle.jpg',
        }
    },
    SimilarityThreshold=threshold,
)
return response['SourceImageFace'], response['FaceMatches']

 # --------------- Main handler ------------------


def lambda_handler(event, context):
print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object'] 
['key'].encode('utf8'))
key_target = "targett/" + key
try:
    response = compare_faces(bucket, key, key_target)
    print(response)
#       mypayload = json.dumps(response)
#      iotResponse = iot.publish(
 #         topic="rekognition/result",
 #        qos=1,
 #       payload=mypayload)
  #  print(iotResponse)
   # return iotResponse
    print(response)
    return response
 except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Error processing object {} from bucket {}. ".format(key, 
 bucket) 
 +
          "Make sure your object and bucket exist and your bucket is in 
 the 
 same region as this function.")
    raise e


 ---------------output-----------------
  Response:
[
{
"BoundingBox": {
  "Width": 0.7813892960548401,
  "Top": 0.15193353593349457,
  "Left": 0.1047489121556282,
  "Height": 0.8365015387535095
  },
  "Confidence": 99.99993896484375
 },
 []
 ]
```

Comment: i can't see the targett variable here please define the targett variable

Comment: i am not able to identify how to declare and compare to target s3 bucket

Comment: It's working now yet there is a issue while comparing images as it returns result 99% almost for every image even though they r different

Comment: i think  you are having some misunderstanding here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are having some misunderstanding here

```
{
    'FaceMatches': [
        {
            'Face': {
                'BoundingBox': {
                    'Height': 0.33481481671333313,
                    'Left': 0.31888890266418457,
                    'Top': 0.4933333396911621,
                    'Width': 0.25,
                },
                'Confidence': 99.9991226196289,
            },
            'Similarity': 100,
        },
    ],
    'SourceImageFace': {
        'BoundingBox': {
            'Height': 0.33481481671333313,
            'Left': 0.31888890266418457,
            'Top': 0.4933333396911621,
            'Width': 0.25,
        },
        'Confidence': 99.9991226196289,
    },
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

Here the confidence score does'nt show weather the face matches or not it shows that it found the face in the image. "Similarty" shows the actual match of the image.

Comment: But if I'm comparing 2 images then it should show weather they are matching or not because  compare_faces is used for that I guess

Comment: But if I'm using a male image and female image it should show less confidence it's showing me 99%

Comment: And I'm not getting the similarity portion from your code

Comment: Confidence score has nothing to do with face matching confidence score shows if there is face present in the image and draw a bounding box around it

Comment: Okay but what about similarity?

Comment: ya its the thing you are looking for

Comment: similarity between two faces

Comment: can you post the full response here ?

Comment: Yes I have done that in the output portion only those lines are getting printed on execution

Comment: are you sure both of your images have faces in them ?

Comment: Definitely it's Obama and michelle obama

Comment: i'm not entirely sure but i have doubts about this line   return response['SourceImageFace'], response['FaceMatches'] please print the payload as its

Comment: also try to reduce the similarity  threshold to 5 or below that and try to upload pictures of similar persons

Comment: I tried some changes when I'm comparing similar images example Obama = Obama gives me similarity that is 100%,  but when I try comparing Obama = Michelle it returns only confidence

Comment: ya i got you that's the whole point, it doesn't return similarity because the similary is less than 75% and you set the similarity threshold to 75 yourself

Comment: Now after changing it to 5 % it gives me similarity 45% for Obama=Michelle

Comment: that's right, now its up to you what threshold you want to keep it depends on type of application

Comment: but as my personal recommendation keep it above 90%

Comment: But for unmatched data it should give me very less similarity value for which I kept  it 5  and this gave me similarity of 45%

Comment: i think you do not quite understand what does "similarity threshold" means here it means aws would only return the similarity for the images where it would be confident above the given "similarity threshold" parameter

Comment: and by the way 45% is nothing in machine learning i recommend you to learn some basics of machine learning always keep the threshold above 90% even 90% is not enough in machine learning

Comment: Okay I get it now the code was all right after initial changes its was only the matter of threshold value

Comment: ya tha's true please mark it as solved so that it can help others with same issue

Comment: you should change the question if you want @john answer to be accepted your response will rather confuse the users otherwise mark my answer as accepted

Comment: Okay I'll do so

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
TargetImage={
    "S3Object": {
        "Bucket": targett,
        "Name": obama.jpg,
    }
```

should be:

```
TargetImage={
    "S3Object": {
        "Bucket": 'targett',
        "Name": key_target,
    }
```

Comment: should the bucket variable be defined before def compare_faces

Comment: `bucket` is being defined in `lambda_handler()`, which is passing it to `compare_faces()`. Seems fine assuming that you want the output to be in the same bucket.

Comment: I am having to buckets having identical images in them i want to compare this images using compare_faces()...How should i define the sourceimage and targetimage. Steps you asked i did that yet the code will throw the same error

Comment: Are the two images in the _same_ or _different_ buckets?

Comment: different bucket one of them is named targett

Comment: Ah! That wasn't obvious. I've updated the suggested code.

Comment: code is running now but its not actually doing comparison when i try changing comparing with seprate images it will give 99% confidence`[
  {
    "BoundingBox": {
      "Width": 0.7813892960548401,
      "Top": 0.15193353593349457,
      "Left": 0.1047489121556282,
      "Height": 0.8365015387535095
    },
    "Confidence": 99.99993896484375
  },
  []
]`

Comment: Even when im comparing a image of male and female